# pam_tally2 does not tally failed logins for failed SSH login attempts

Tags: linux, ssh, pam

**Goal**

For mobile devices we wish to add an extra layer of security by requiring a PIN code upon ssh login. Mobile access is only a convenience service (users can always pull out their laptops) and accounts should be locked permanently after three attempts at the PIN code (administrators can unlock an account). Administrators will generate a random new PIN upon unlocking.

**Method**

To prompt for a password after public key authentication, I added the following to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`:

```
Match Group RequireSSHPassword
AuthenticationMethods publickey,password
```

Any user that is in the RequireSSHPassword group will be asked for a password in addition to public key authentication. `UsePAM` is set to `yes` earlier in the config file. Attempting to add this to the `Match` results in `sshd` failing to start ("Directive 'UsePAM' is not allowed within a Match block").

For lockout, the PAM module `pam_tally2` seems to be the way to go.
**This is what fails to work.**

As per [this question on the Unix SE site](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78182/how-to-lock-users-after-5-unsuccessful-login-tries), I added the following lines to `/etc/pam.d/common-password`:

```
auth        required            pam_tally2.so file=/var/log/tallylog deny=3 onerr=fail
account     required            pam_tally2.so
```

I also tried adding only the `auth` line, or adding one or both to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, or adding the `account` line to `/etc/pam.d/common-account`, or shuffling the order of the lines, all to no avail. The environment is Debian Stretch (testing).

The `/var/log/tallylog` file is not created when attempting to log in with an incorrect password. After using the command `pam_tally2 --user=test`, the file is created and empty. After using the command `pam_tally2 --user=test --reset=3`, the file is filled with 64K binary data. Using `pam_tally2 --user=test` now shows 3 failed attempts with no source (as expected).

When trying to log in while the tally is set to 3 (so the user should be locked out), I cannot. No error is given, it just says the login attempt failed (just as if I had used an invalid password). So it actually appears to work. However, when resetting the tally to 0, I can do 3 attempts with incorrect password and still login on a 4th attempt. Using `pam_tally2 --user=test`, the number of failures is still 0, even if I do 1 attempt with an incorrect password and then close the ssh connection.

The limiting appears to be in effect when I manually update the tally counter, but the tally counter does not appear to get updated, if I interpret events correctly.

In `/var/log/auth.log` I can see the failed login attempts for the user. From all the testing, there have been two messages in `auth.log` from tally:

```
Mar  6 11:36:17 HOST sshd[18906]: pam_tally2(sshd:auth): user test (1xxx) tally 4, deny 3
Mar  6 12:49:40 HOST sshd[20392]: pam_tally2(sshd:account): option deny=3 allowed in auth phase only
```

The latter came when I tried to specify the options on the `account` line (additionally to the `auth` line). The former probably came from trying to log in after manually having reset failed logins to 3.

Changing the mode of the `tallylog` to `0777`, it errors about being world-writable. Changing owner to `sshd` in mode `0774` does not change anything (just in case ssh did not have write permissions for `tallylog`, which by default was in mode `0600` with owner and group `root`).

Because of the log messages and because of the lockout after using `--reset=3`, I believe the module is being used. For some reason it appears to either not notice failed logins, or not able to update the `tallylog`. How could I debug this? Or should I use something else instead?

---

By the way, `fail2ban` is another common solution which I've reviewed. However, the manual for the latest version (0.8) mentions it works by scanning log files every second. As the manual says, "Lots of syslog daemons buffer their outputs." On top of that, many login attempts can be performed in a single second by parallelization. Fail2ban is not suitable in this case, where the point is not to block brute force attempts on normal accounts, but to block a specialized attacker that already has my private key and now needs to brute a few digits.

Comment: Any chance you ever solved this?

Comment: @ljden I don't think I pursued this further at the time. Thinking about the problem again now, I'm not actually sure how much a PIN helps if a compromised private key means that they have device access anyway and could also capture the PIN. It would give more peace of mind for the hour that a stolen device is not yet blocked, though the overlap in the venn diagram of people that would know/want to login via ssh but did not specifically target me (and found out my PIN in some way) is very small. Sorry I cannot help, but depending on circumstances, an alternative solution might be better anyway

Comment: Not so much looking at the pin component as the pam_tally2 issues you had. I have similar issues that I'm trying to work through